# $v \subseteq H \implies V^\bot$ is a closed subspace of the Hilbert space $H$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products, orthogonality

**Exercise :**

> Show that if $H$ is a Hilbert space and $V \subseteq H$, then $V^\bot$ is a closed subspace of $H$.

**Attempt :**

I thought of two possible approaches. One would be a classic one, getting an arbitrary sequence $v_n \in V^\bot$ and showing that $\lim v_n = v \in V^\bot$. The other one would be showing that $V^\bot = (V^\bot)^{\bot\bot}$, which implies that $V^\bot$ is a closed subspace of $H$.

For my first approach, let $v_n \in V^\bot$ and $v_n \to h \in H$ . Then, for all $v \in V$, it is :

$$\langle x,v \rangle = \langle \lim v_n, v\rangle = \lim\langle v_n, v\rangle =0 \implies x \in V^\bot $$

That's really straightforward and simple.

I am wondering how would one complete my thought for my second possible approach, meaningly showing that $V^\bot = (V^\bot)^{\bot\bot}$. I seem a little rusty on that.

Comment: $V^\perp$, by definition, is the intersection of closed subspaces, once you show that it is true for a singleton $V=\{v\}$

Comment: Also I believe that your second approach is a vicious circle, because how do you prove that $A=(A^\perp)^\perp$ implies that $A$ is closed? You invoke this result that you want to prove now

Comment: @Federico Thanks for your first input, but it's not needed as I've already proven what needs to be proven. My question is strictly regarding my second approach. It is already proven that $ A = A^{\bot\bot}$ implies that $A$ is closed, thus no need for any elaboration.

Comment: Honestly, I really doubt that one can prove "$V=(V^\perp)^\perp \implies V \text{ is closed}$" without already knowing that $W^\perp$ is closed for any $W$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you already know that (1) $X\subseteq (X^\bot)^\bot$ for all sets $X$ and (2) if $X\subseteq Y$ then $X^\bot\supseteq Y^\bot$. (If not, just check that both facts follow immediately from the definition of ${\ }^\bot$.)

Apply (1) with $V$ as your $X$ to get $V\subseteq(V^\bot)^\bot$ and then use (2) to get $V^\bot\supseteq((V^\bot)^\bot)^\bot$.

On the other hand, if you apply (1) with $V^\bot$ as your $X$, then you get $V^\bot\subseteq((V^\bot)^\bot)^\bot$.

So you have inclusions in both directions, and therefore $V^\bot=((V^\bot)^\bot)^\bot$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: An arbitrary intersection of closed subspaces is a closed subspace.

Comment: See my comment to the question. But actually, proving it for a generic $V$ as he does is not more complicated than proving ti for $V=\{v\}$